# Google Chrome Developer Tools has stopped logging output and errors to the console?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm currently running Google Chrome version 31.0.1622.7 and since about 2 days ago my dev tools stopped logging any of my output (e.g. `console.log("Blah.."`), or displaying any errors to the console.  If an error occurs I can see the red error icon in the bottom right of the window, but if I click on the icon it doesn't show the error details in the console window or highlight the error in the source.

I have tried re-installing Chrome and the problems persists.  Is anyone else experiencing this issue, and/or have a solution to it?

Comment: Can this be related - http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=21734 ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

On the bottom of the devtools window, to the left of the error and warning icons, there should be a set of console output filter buttons. See below for a description of the filter options. ***Note the funnel button*** to the left of the "All" button.

[image]

You must check the type of output you want in the funnel-menu. The funnel menu is active for all filter-button options. So if you select the "Logs" button but have "Logging" unchecked in the funnel-menu, there will be no logging output. Both funnel-menu and filter-buttons can be multi-selected. Ctrl-click, Windows, or Cmd-click, OSX, to select multiple filter-buttons.

From the [docs](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console#console_settings)

- All—Shows all console output.
- Errors—Only show output from console.error()
- Warnings—Only show output from console.warn()
- Logs—Only show output from console.log(), console.info() and console.debug().
- Debug—Only show output from console.timeEnd() and other console output

Comment: Aaaah!  Thank you, completely didn't spot that! (I thought it was a bit odd that no one else was shouting about it.)

Answer (score 12):

I had same problem and i solved by **Restore defaults and reload chrome** settings.

You can follow this way:

1. Open DevTools by pressing F12 or ctrl + shift + i.
2. Press F1 or click on tree dots on the top right corner and select settings in this menu.
3. Scroll at the bottom or to the right of screen and press [restore defaults and reload] button.

Answer (score 7):

I had this same problem (for five frustrating days) and it was because I had inadvertently typed something in the "Filter" field. And then once I deleted that, all my messages came back.