# Nothing appears on the DevTools console when I type and I can't change or modify anything

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

When I try to enter, modify or change anything in the devtools Elements or in the Console nothing is happening, I keep typing and entering but nothing is happening.

Can anyone help me with this issue?

I'm running Version 32.0.1687.2 dev-m Aura, I disabled all the extensions but still the same issue.

Any help is appreciated,

Comment: Is it possible the DevTools console is set to filter out logging? See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18655354/google-chrome-developer-tools-has-stopped-logging-output-and-errors-to-the-conso/18674385#18674385) for details.

Comment: For me, the problem was that the cursor was missing but restarting Vivaldi solved it.